# Display master volume control slider (sndvol.exe) programmatically in correct position

Tags: c++, windows-8

Just bought a new Toshiba Satellite Z930 and was disappointed to find no volume up/down function keys provided. However, the ultrabook **does** have two programmable keys next to the power button, so I'm trying to develop a small C++ app that I can call from these keys.

So far all of my code is working great to increase/decrease the volume based upon a command-line parameter passed to the program. The only problem I'm having is that I want to display the master volume slider to let the user know that the operation worked, and I want it to appear in the normal position that it appears in when you click on the speaker icon in the notification area.

ATM I'm simply using CreateProcess() to run "sndvol.exe -f", which works but displays the window in an odd location (roughly {100, 400}). So I then attempt to get a handle to the window via EnumWindows() and GetWindowThreadProcessId(), and move it to the location I want using SetWindowPos(), but this has no effect. I can successfully get a handle to the process's top-level window, but can't move it!

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Would it have anything to do with the fact that taking focus off the slider window closes it? [This](https://superuser.com/questions/440751/windows-7-open-the-volume-control-popup-from-the-command-prompt) page suggests that what I'm trying to achieve **is** possible, so what am I doing wrong?

MTIA :D

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply but nope, that doesn't help :( If I set both si.dwX and si.dwY to 5, they still hold this value after the CreateProcess call, but the window still appears in the original location :( TA

Comment: (I've tried it in the meantime and deleted the comment. See my answer, that is working for me.)

Comment: Why not just remap the keys to hardware volume control keys?

Comment: @RaymondChen That would be great if I knew how! LOL :P

Comment: You can SendInput the scan codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this interesting combination of STARTUPINFO and SetWindowPos seems to work:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    const DWORD myProcessId = (DWORD) lParam;

    DWORD processId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &processId);
    if (processId == myProcessId) {
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    wchar_t cmdline[33000] = L" -f";
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    BOOL x = CreateProcess(L"c:\\Windows\\System32\\sndvol.exe", &cmdline[0], 0, 0, true, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
    //std::cerr << x << " " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    {
        x = EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM) pi.dwProcessId);
        //std::cerr << x << " " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        Sleep(20);
    }

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return 0;
}
```

You might want to experiment more for a better solution (e.g. watch if the callback succeeds moving the window at least `k` times. I've tried checking one time success and it did not move the window always. Also be sure to check that your process handles still refer to a valid process - you don't want to write an endless loop.).

Although with the latest edit the solution became quite reliable.

Comment: Thanks heaps for trying to help but this doesn't work for me...copied your code verbatim into a new VC++ console project and ran it but got the same results as in my own app :( What OS did you run this code on? I'm on Windows 8 so maybe that's the culprit...

Comment: Hello! The `WaitForInputIdle()` seems to wait too short in some cases (for me it worked in Debug but not in Release). Changing that to `Sleep(1000)` works better. Tried on Windows 7 and 8. You might want to experiment more for a better solution (e.g. watch if the callback succeeds moving the window at least `k` times.).

Comment: OK yeah I see what you mean...I just followed your suggestion to change the WaitForInputIdle() call to a Sleep() call, and the first time I ran it, it worked! But now I can't get it to work again...I've tried many different values for Sleep()'s dwMilliseconds parameter, but to no avail :( So how the heck can we make this RELIABLY work ALL THE TIME?!?! This is really starting to P.O. me...but thanks again for all your help! :)

Comment: Made it more reliable. Moving the window more times seem to ensure to overwrite the default placement.

Comment: Yes this works much better; thank you yet again! I was also returning FALSE from EnumWindowsProc() after moving the window so this was interfering with the process as well! But all is working great now thx to you! :D

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/mark this as a solution then.

Comment: Note: returning FALSE after moving the window should not make a difference. The main point is repeating the `EnumWindows` call.

Answer (score -1):

From "out of the box", instead of working the position of the window from your code, add the command line argument in the CreateProcess call, as you can contemplate [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/198083-volume-mixer-shortcut-create.html%20(OPTION%20TWO)%20https://superuser.com/questions/440751/windows-7-open-the-volume-control-popup-from-the-command-prompt) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/440751/windows-7-open-the-volume-control-popup-from-the-command-prompt). The letter argument in the examples can be omitted, obviously.
I'm not sure if i can do the math myself, not familiar from where the coordinates start, but it seems to be a possible solution.